# How to create a Javascript array from xml file attributes in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using [jqGrid](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html), but it cannot take attributes from a xml file. So I wanted to have a array out the xml something like below. Please help me create an array from the xml file below

jqGrid supported array format

```
var mydata = [
    {id:"1",invdate:"2007-10-01",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
    {id:"2",invdate:"2007-10-02",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
    {id:"3",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"},
    {id:"4",invdate:"2007-10-04",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
    {id:"5",invdate:"2007-10-05",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
    {id:"6",invdate:"2007-09-06",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"},
    {id:"7",invdate:"2007-10-04",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
    {id:"8",invdate:"2007-10-03",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
    {id:"9",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"}
    ];
```

My xml

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="csmclientiir.xsl"?>
<csmclient product="abc"   date="4/26/11 2:05 PM">
<system>
<osname>Linux
</osname>
<hostname>AbhishekNix
</hostname>
<release>2.6.18-128.el5
</release>
<filesystem>
    <file mount='/home/hp1' home='(innfs2:/vol/home/shome/home/hp1)' total='1717567488' free='644306780' used='1073260708' percentage='62' />
    <file mount='/home/par21' home='(innfs2:/vol/home/shome/home/par21)' total='1717567488' free='644306780' used='1073260708' percentage='62' />
    <file mount='/home/h231' home='(innfs2:/vol/home/shome/home/h231)' total='1717567488' free='644306780' used='1073260708' percentage='62' />
    <file mount='/home/avallin1' home='(innfs2:/vol/home/shome/home/avallin1)' total='1717567488' free='644306780' used='1073260708' percentage='62' />
    <file mount='/home/park' home='(innfs2:/vol/home/shome/home/park)' total='1717567488' free='644306780' used='1073260708' percentage='62' />
    <file mount='/home/sp1' home='(innfs2:/vol/home/shome/home/sp1)' total='1717567488' free='644306780' used='1073260708' percentage='62' />
    <file mount='/home/ganga1' home='(innfs2:/vol/home/shome/home/ganga1)' total='1717567488' free='644306780' used='1073260708' percentage='62' />
    <file mount='/home/nbp1' home='(innfs2:/vol/home/shome/home/nbp1)' total='1717567488' free='644306780' used='1073260708' percentage='62' />
</filesystem>
</system>
<product>
<showtime>Tue Apr 26 14:05:23 2011
</showtime>
</product>
</csmclient>
```

How to create a JS array in jquery or JS, out of the above xml for the attributes under `csmclient>system>filesystem>file` eg: `mount`, `free`, `total`, `used` and `percentage` attributes

**Updated**

```
var filesystem=[];
$(xml).find('file').each(function(){ 
    console.info($(this).attr('total')+", "+$(this).attr('free')+", "+$(this).attr('used')+", "+$(this).attr('percentage'));
    var row={};
    row.total=$(this).attr('total');
    row.free=$(this).attr('free');
    row.used=$(this).attr('used');
    row.percentage=$(this).attr('percentage');
    filesystem.push(row);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var data = [];

$(xml).find('file').each(function(){ 
  var row = {};
  row.mount = this.getAttribute("mount");
  // ...
  data.push(row);
});
```

Comment: How can i verify that `data` has the exact structure as in jqGrid requirement, after I have used my xml parsing on it? I updated my question part

Comment: @Ricky: When you build `data` according to that spec, then it will have the required structure. Or what am I missing from that qestion?

Comment: Sorry my bad, i was doing a mistake i was adding to `data` while it should have been `filesystem` in my case, i'll check and get back. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

use a jQuery **[XSLT](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/xslt)** plugin to transform the xml to the proper format.

```
XML --> [XSLT Transformation] --> JS
```

This layer between the source (XML) and the output (JS) gives you the freedom to maintain, change and expand the source and the output without creating spaghetti.

An XSLT to JSON tutorial can be found [here](http://www.bizcoder.com/index.php/2010/02/12/convert-xml-to-json-using-xslt/)

---

EDIT: A sample implementation would look like

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
>
  <xsl:output method="text" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="csmclient/system/filesystem" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="filesystem">
    <xsl:text>[</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="file" />
    <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="file">
    <xsl:text>{</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
    <xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
    <xsl:if test="position() &lt; last()">,</xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="file/@*">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('&quot;', name(), '&quot;:')" />
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="string(number(.)) = 'NaN'">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('&quot;',. , '&quot;')" />
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:if test="position() &lt; last()">,</xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @Casper: Any quick link to get started and convert the attributes to nodes, also will the xml get persisted, coz I don't want that. My xml structure should preserve